# How to call function from App.js file inside public folder in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to call a function which is defined inside src/App.js (callMe) from public folder,

In `App.js`

```
import messaging from './firebase-init';
import './App.css';

function App () {
 function callMe() {
   console.log('Call me function called');
 }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And I've another file **firebase-messaging-sw.js** located inside public folder,

In `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  console.log('On notification click: ', event);
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
    includeUncontrolled: true,
    type: "window",
  }).then(function (clientList) {
    console.log('********* clientList: ', clientList);
    for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
      var client = clientList[i];
      if (client.url !== '' && 'focus' in client) {
        client.focus();
        callMe();  // This function is defined in src/App.js
        break;
      }
    }
  }));
});

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const initializedFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Can you please help me, how should I call function **callMe()** ?

Comment: You can create a custom event and listen for that event in the App component.

Comment: Could you please explain in example way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `postMessage`
[window.postMessage spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

simply send Message in your .js file

```
window.postMessage('someFunctionId','*')
```

and then in react you can add eventListener for this message (best solution is in useEffect and dont forget to removeListener on callback)

```
useEffect(()=>{
window.addEventListener("message",handlerFunc);
return ()=> window.removeEventListener("message",handlerFunc);
}
```

and ind your `handlerFunc` you can just check if message is the same as your ID as you posted...

you can even pass object instad of string to pass some parameters for your function

```
window.postMessage({id:'someFunctionId',data:'test'},'*');
```

Comment: Even I also tried this method before, but I'm getting "window" is undefined then after that I tried only postMessage then also same error like postMessage is undefined

Comment: in your plain JS you propably need first to check if window exists ```if (window !== undefined) {
 window.postMessage('someFunctionId','*')
}```

Comment: Hello Wraithy,
I tried above method but that is going inside function. Still it is giving bellow error,
"Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: window is not defined "

Comment: Hence I'm checking the window value using string like,

console.log('>>>>>>>>>>');
if (typeof window != "undefined") {
     console.log('&&&&&&&& ');
      window.postMessage({ id: 'someFunctionId', data: 'test' }, '*');
 }

Even after also it is not going inside function. 
hmmm.
I'm surprise why window is coming as undefined inside firebase-messaging-sw.js file

Comment: I have no Idea... where do you running this .js file? if its run using node.js there is no window

Comment: This is my react js application